# Equity finance and primary brokerage and their products

Tags: collateral, repo

I was in the project working on the asset classes known as **EF/PB**, which is short for **Equity Fiance / Primary brokerage**, I understand that Equity finance is more or less about securities lending, and my manager told me that the product of the EF is repo.

I understand securities lending and repo conceptually, but there are some more details I'd like to hammer out:

- As a dealer-broker, which is what my firm is, is it that we loan out
  the securities and hold collateral from the counter-parties, or the other
  way too? Normally how does the business flow and how the risk is assessed?
- the word **Loanet** pops up once a while and I found online it only links
  to one firm, **SunGuard**. I take that it isn't a general term rather the
  product from SunGuard? Can anyone clarify/elaborate on it?
- How about primary brokerage? I understand there are primary dealers
  who are prodigiously qualified to participate in Treasury&Fed's bond
  auctions. But when it's used in the context as an asset class, what
  does it mean and what're its products?

Sorry I should have thrown these questions at my boss but I am no long with the firm.

Comment: In the third question, by primary brokerage do you mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_brokerage ?

Comment: thanks @noob2 - yes, it looks this is the one.

Comment: 1st question: broker dealers both borrow and lend securities. 2d question: you are right that Loanet is a proprietary system for borrowing/lending securities that belongs to and is run by Sunguard.